# Codename One change color of Material Icons

Tags: icons, codenameone

I am using the new Gui Builder and would like to change the color and size of the Material icons in a button.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything related on the net and changing the button's font color does not seem to affect  the color of the icon ...

Thanks in advance.

What I have so far is the css style :

```
mybutton {

    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 4pt;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 2pt 2pt 2pt 0px gray;
    color: #ff0000;
    font-family:  "native:MainRegular";
    font-size: 7pt;
    margin-top: 5pt;
    margin-bottom: 12pt;
    padding-bottom: 2mm;
    padding-top: 2mm;
    text-align: center;
```

}[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The material icons get the color and styling of the component they apply to including changing their color on press/disable. To change their color just customize the UIID of the component e.g. if the component UIID is `MyButton` just style the `MyButton` UIID in the designer to match the color you want for the icon.

Comment: Shai, thanks for your swift reply.  One way to change the color of the icons is through css (code added above). One doubt remains: Following your instructions (customize the UIID of the component), I have defined the UIID like this: gui_button_Accept.setUIID("mybutton"). But I got stuck by adding the component to the theme. The manual tells to press the ADD BUTTON and fill in the component's UIID in the tab that opens. When I write "mybutton" in the text field and press ENTER, I was expecting a new tab to be added to the list of the selectors, what doesn't occur. What am I missing?

Comment: There should be a new line added, you can do this thru CSS just fine but generally this is how you do it in the designer tool: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change the color of the material icons is by adjusting the foreground color of  Default Style, in the theme editor. But this only works when you don't activate the CN1 internal ccs support.